# How do I pass current logged in username with an Intent to be able to use it in various Activities

Tags: php, android, sql, android-intent, authentication

Lately I've been working on doing pretty much my own social app. I have already finished my `LoginActivity` and started designing my `NavigationDrawer` activity and fragments. But I want the app to detect which user is currently online to be able to use their username in `TextViews` and etc.. I specifically want it to display this :

[image: here(Image)]

Here is LoginActivity

```html
package co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.android.md5simply.MD5;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.ExceptionHandler;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.R;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    EditText etEmail, etPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    TextView tvRegister;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

        tvRegister = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);
        tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean emptyValidate(EditText etEmail, EditText etPassword){
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        return (email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty());
    }
    String password = "";
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        password =  MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString());

        HashMap<String, String> loginData = new HashMap<>();
        loginData.put("email", email);
        loginData.put("password", password);

        PostResponseAsyncTask loginTask = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, loginData, new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, s);
                if(s.contains("LoginSuccess")){
                    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("loginData", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("email", email);
                    editor.putString("password", password);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fallo al iniciar sesion.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        loginTask.setExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleException(Exception e) {
                if(e != null && e.getMessage() != null){
                    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        loginTask.execute("https://luisalonsoriveraibarra.000webhostapp.com/conecciones%20y%20demas/login.php");
    }
}
```

Here is my NavigationDrawer Activity

```html
package co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.clases.Utilidades;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.fragments.ContenedorFragment;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.fragments.FormularioFragment;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.fragments.GreenFragment;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.fragments.ListaPersonajesFragment;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.fragments.RedFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        RedFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,GreenFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        FormularioFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,ContenedorFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        ListaPersonajesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (Utilidades.validaPantalla==true){
            Fragment fragment=new ContenedorFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,fragment).commit();
            Utilidades.validaPantalla=false;
        }



        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment miFragment=null;
        boolean fragmentSeleccionado=false;


        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            miFragment=new ContenedorFragment();
            fragmentSeleccionado=true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"No disponible",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"No disponible",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            miFragment=new GreenFragment();
            fragmentSeleccionado=true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            miFragment=new GreenFragment();
            fragmentSeleccionado=true;
        }

        if (fragmentSeleccionado==true){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,miFragment).commit();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Login.php

```html
<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty(isset($_POST['email'])) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty(isset($_POST['password']))){
 include_once("connection.php");
 
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 
    $sql = "SELECT email, password FROM table_user WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
 
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "LoginSuccess";
 } else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }

}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your MainActivity.java:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
name = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.username);
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String myStrValue = prefs.getString("email", "your default string");
name.setText(myStrValue);
```

Comment: Already did something similar before and worked, but I wanted to see if it can work with php so that the server knows which user is using that phone